# Does element type in std::vector need to be movable to allow move semantics on return by value?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Does MyType have to be "movable" for the compiler to be able to apply move semantics when returning v from foo()?

```
std::vector<MyType> foo() {
    std::vector<MyType> v;
    // populate v
    return v;
}
```

Comment: NRVO (a specific form of copy elision) wouldn't use "move" semantics at all; it would just directly construct into the space allocated for the return value by the caller.

Comment: Putting aside the choice of example, `std::vector` is movable regardless of the element type. The elements are neither moved nor copied when moving an `std::vector`.

Comment: Sounds like I mixed up NRVO and move semantics. What would be a clean example of move semantics on return then in this context? Return of a std::vector typed member variable?

Answer (score 3):

No, vector does not need your type to be moveable in order for the vector itself to be moveable.  Essentially a vector is

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
private:
    T* start;
    T* end;
    T* capcity_end;
public:
    ...
    vector(vector&& old) : start(old.start), end(old.end), capcity_end(old.capcity_end) {
        old.start = old.end = old.capcity_end = nullptr;
    }
    ...
};
```

And when the vector moves, it just copies the pointer values into the new vector, and sets to pointers to `nullptr` in the old vector so that they do not get cleaned up by the destructor.  With this, `T` doesn't even need to be copyable, as no elements are being copied/moved, it's just pointers getting swapped.

Comment: That's what I thought but a coworker said the elements need to be movable too so I thought I might be missing something. Perhaps I misunderstood what he was trying to say.

Comment: @VladG Maybe they were talking about when a vector resizes.  In those cases, your type needs to be noexcept move constructible in order for vector to move the elements from the old buffer into the new larger buffer, otherwise it falls back to copying the elements from the old buffer into the new buffer.

Comment: yeah, that's probably what they meant, although we started the talk about return values and then it morphed...

Comment: With discussions like this with coworkers, try out examples on godbolt.org and you’ll settle disagreements/confusions quickly.